# How can we select columns from a pandas dataframe based on a certain condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and i want to create a list of columns for one particular variable if `P_BUYER` column has one entry greater than 97 and others less . For example, below, a list should be created containing `TENRACT` and `ADV_INC`. If `P_BUYER` has a value greater than or equal to 97 then the value which is in parallel to T for that particular block should be saved in a list (e.g. we have following values in parallel to `T` in below example : `(TENRCT,ADVNTG_MARITAL,NEWLSGOLFIN,ADV_INC)`

```
Input :

T                     TENRCT          P_NONBUY(%)   P_BUYER(%)  INDEX   PBIN    NEWBIN
N (1,2,3) = Renter    N (1,2,3) = Renter    35.88   0.1           33    8        2
Q <0> = Unknown      Q <0> = Unknown        3.26    0.1           36    8        2
Q1 <4> = Owner       Q <4> = Owner          60.86   99.8          143   5        1          
E2          
T                ADVNTG_MARITAL      P_NONBUY(%)    P_BUYER(%)  INDEX   PBIN    NEWBIN
Q2<1> = 1+Marrd  Q<1> = 1+Marrd   52.91         78.98       149      5      2
Q<2> = 1+Sngl        Q<2> = 1+Sngl    45.23         17.6        39       8      3
Q1<3> = Mrrd_Sngl   Q<3> = Mrrd_Sngl 1.87           3.42        183      4      1
E3                      
T                  ADV_INC           P_NONBUY(%)    P_BUYER(%)  INDEX   PBIN    NEWBIN
N1('1','Y') = Yes   N('1','Y') = Yes     3.26       1.2         182     4       1
N('0','-1')= No N('0','-1')= No      96.74      98.8        97      7       2
E2
```

output:

```
Finallist=['TENRACT','ADV_INC']
```

Comment: Please reformat your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
# In your code, you have 3 dataframes E1,E2,E3, iterate over them
output = []
for df in [E1,E2,E3]:
    # Filter you dataframe
    df = df[df['P_BUYER(%)'] >= 97 ]
    if not df.empty:
       cols = df.columns.values.tolist()
       # Find index of 'T' column
       t_index = cols.index('T')
       # You desired parallel column will be at t_index+1
       output.append(cols[t_index+1])
print(output)
```

Comment: Hi @Ayush Thanks for the reply but i dont have 3 dataframes ,i have one single dataframe and E1,E3 these are values in dataframe generated on the basis of highest level of newbin value. For eg : In ADVNTG_MARITAL, the highest newbin value is 3 so the code will write E3 below the block of ADVNTG_MARITAL

Comment: @MansiArora Can you please edit the input code and post your dataframe again with proper formatting?The way it is posted now makes it look like 3 dataframes.

Comment: I will post it again but the structure is same as i posted it above..the row with E2,E3 are rows of this dataframe with empty values in all columns except the first one